# How to get active cell address of excel sheet in vb.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

How to get the address of a cell by clicking on an Excel sheet?
I have C# code working with it, but in VB.Net it gives an error

```
Public Sub ws_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)

    fieldaddress.Text = Target.Address
    'Target.Address.ToString() = lboToUnit.SelectedItem.ToString
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    ws = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet
    ws.SelectionChange += **ws_SelectionChange()**

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error? Which line triggers it? FWIW in VSTO the code you've added to `OnLoad` does not belong there. It belongs in the `ThisAddIn_StartUp` procedure - in both C# and VB.NET..

Comment: Thanku @Cindy for answering ...  can u help me how can i insert my selected combobox value into a selected cell address (got from range function ) which is in my form text field in this format " $g$2" ............using vb.net

Comment: Did you *read* my full comment? Until you've taken all the actions mentioned there, there's nothing more anyone can do. And if you need further help after doing those things, please provide a [mcve].